# Xpath to select only nodes where child elements exist?

Tags: xpath

This should be an easy one but it is giving me trouble.  Given this structure:

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b/>
  </a>
  <a/>
</root>
```

I'm trying to formulate an xpath expression that gives only the non-empty "a" elements, i.e. the ones that have child elements.  Therefore I want the first instance of "a" returned, but not the second.

So far I have "/root/a/self::*" but that is returning me both a's.

Comment: I also found that this works:

/root/a[child::*]

But I'll give Adrian credit for an answer that also works!  :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
/root/a[count(*)&gt;0]
```

will give any 'a' node with any kind of child node

Comment: Just as an extra point, you can use count(b) to be specific about which child nodes you want to count.

Answer (score 8):

```
/root/a[count(*)>0]
```

Comment: Only if you want to put it into an XML file (e.g. an XSLT script). Still, that's just a storage detail, I'm pretty sure the XPath spec uses ">" :)

Answer (score 5):

This one works

```
/root/a[*]
```

or even

```
//a[*]
```

Comment: Or if you only care about child elements with name "b": `/root/a[b]`