# Select parent element only if child element has specific number of elements

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I  am trying to fetch all `<Opening>` tag whose `<PlanarGeometry>`'s `<Polyloop>` has number of `CartesianPoint` > 4.

Xml tag surface is child of another.

```
<Surface id="su-137" surfaceType="InteriorWall" constructionIdRef="ASHIW23" xmlns="http://www.gbxml.org/schema">
 <Name>W-106-114-I-W-137</Name>
 <Opening id="su-137-op-1" openingType="NonSlidingDoor" constructionIdRef="MDOOR">
 <Name>W-106-114-I-W-137-D-1</Name>
   <PlanarGeometry>
      <PolyLoop> 
         <CartesianPoint><Coordinate>55.570238</Coordinate><Coordinate>92.571596</Coordinate>
         <Coordinate>0.000000</Coordinate></CartesianPoint><CartesianPoint>         <Coordinate>55.570238</Coordinate><Coordinate>92.571596</Coordinate><Coordinate>6.666667</Coordinate>     
         </CartesianPoint>
         <CartesianPoint>
         <Coordinate>55.570238</Coordinate><Coordinate>95.571596</Coordinate><Coordinate>6.666667</Coordinate></CartesianPoint>
         <CartesianPoint>
         <Coordinate>55.570238</Coordinate><Coordinate>95.571596</Coordinate><Coordinate>0.000000</Coordinate>
        </CartesianPoint>
     </PolyLoop>
   </PlanarGeometry>
 </Opening>              
</Surface>
```

I got little reference from this - [Xpath to select only nodes where child elements exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143864/xpath-to-select-only-nodes-where-child-elements-exist) SO thread and got little help from below example.

```
book[author/degree]
All <book> elements that contain <author> children that in turn contain at least one <degree> child.
```

How can i achieve this using xPath or another way???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to fetch all `<Opening>` tag whose `<PlanarGeometry>`'s `<Polyloop>` has number of CartesianPoint > 4.

Assuming the `Surface` element is your current context node then:

```
gb:Opening[gb:PlanarGeometry/gb:Polyloop[count(gb:CartesianPoint) > 4]]
```

The `gb` prefix needs to be mapped to the `http://www.gbxml.org/schema` namespace URI.  This will select all `Opening` elements that contain at least one `Polyloop` with more than 4 `CartesianPoint` children.

Answer (score 1):

The following XPath should work:

```
//g:Opening[4<count(./g:PlanarGeometry/g:PolyLoop/g:CartesianPoint)]
```

Note that it uses a namespace prefix since the `Surface` tag has a namespace. I do not know much C#, but you probably have to register the prefix before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Please give this a try:

```
/gb:Surface/gb:Opening[count(gb:PlanarGeometry/gb:PolyLoop/gb:CartesianPoint) > 4]
```

As shown here, since your XML uses a namespace, you'll need to declare that namespace to your XPath engine and then refer to it by a prefix.  It doesn't have to be `gb`, but it has to be something.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use LINQ to XML, here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            XElement sample = XElement.Load("c:\\sample.xml");
            IEnumerable<XElement> open_elements = sample.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName == "Opening").Where(c => c.Descendants().Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "CartesianPoint").Count() > 4);
            foreach (XElement ele in open_elements){
                Console.Write(ele.Attribute("id"));
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.